# How do I prevent a form from allowing duplicate names

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to not allow duplicate names to be entered by the user in the form that I created.

```
function addKitten(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  let form = event.target

  let kitten = {
    id: generateId(),
    name: form.name.value,
    mood: "Tolerant",
    affection: 5,
  }
  
  console.log(kitten);

  kittens.push(kitten)
  saveKittens()
  form.reset()
  drawKittens()
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that tries to do this already in your post, and an explanation of how that doesn't do what you expected it to do? If you don't want to duplicate names, then the obvious first step is: check the already used names?

Comment: Check the list of kittens for the entered name?

Answer (score 1):

by using `find`

```js
function addKitten(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  let form = event.target

  let kitten = {
    id: generateId(),
    name: form.name.value,
    mood: "Tolerant",
    affection: 5,
  }
  
  const isExist = kittens.find((v) => v.name === form.name.value);
  if(isExist) {
    console.log("Kitten already exist!");
    return;
  }

  kittens.push(kitten)
  saveKittens()
  form.reset()
  drawKittens()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much really appreciative it. I am very new to coding if you have time could you explain how you got to this conclusion or why you used kittens.find

Comment: the .find() syntax will return the first element it find base on your condition. you can check this link to find more about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find